# Looking for a plugin of outlook to @someone

Tags: outlook-addin, thunderbird-addon

I'm looking for a plugin of outlook (or thunderbird). It is to add ***@someone*** in the email body, just like tweeter or group chatting (e.x. wechat). If both the sender and recepients installed the plugin, who is ***@-ed*** will be highlighted in a certain way. This is to attract attention of a certain guy among the many receipients or in a mail list.

p.s.
It would be good if this becomes an standard feature of all email clients.

Comment: Please explain: "who is @-ed will be highlighted in a certain way." Did you mean if the person A is in the recipient list and the same person A is @-ed then on receival of mail by person A,  person A will get some kind of notification which will let him/her know that he/she is mentioned in mail.

Comment: Yes exactly @sameerkn

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for can be achieved by `Creating Rules` in Outlook.
[Manage email messages by using rules.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59)
Using Rules you can specify which words you are looking for in body/subject of mails and what actions can be taken if those words are found.

Alternatively,the feature which you are looking for is kind of customization in Outlook. Someone might have created such `@-ed centric feature` as an Addin, but you can easily create Outlook Addin for this feature.

You can use the Microsoft Office developer tools in Visual Studio to create .NET Framework applications that extend Office. These applications are also named Office solutions.

Through this Addin :

- you can easily get notification of new mails arriving in an account.
- [you can parse the mail body.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935611/retrieve-current-email-body-in-outlook)
- you can display a customized message or mark the mail or highlight it on finding that the recipient of mail has been `@-ed` in the mail body.

You can start creating a simple Addin by following [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx)

Believe me. There are tons of helps related to Outlook Addin development already available on internet in order to guide you in your development process.

Cheers!